# symfony sub query with getDQL query

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

```
$sub = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$sub->select('d')
    ->from($this->entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityClass)->getName(), 'd')
    ->where("d.number != ''")
    ->orderBy('d.time', 'DESC');

*

    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('p')
        ->from($sub->getDQL(),'p')
        ->groupBy('p.number');

*
```

Please correct above subqueries if anything is wrong in it.
It is showing error 
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 14: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ALIASED_NAME, got 'SELECT'

Comment: I am trying to build query
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name d WHERE d.number != '' ORDER BY d.stop_time DESC ) AS p GROUP BY p.number

Comment: Please take a look here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#subqueries

Comment: Samuel Breu
Can you help me in fixing issue in the my code. I am not getting where is the issue

Comment: Please try to solve it like described in the docs, if it still fails, post your new solution and new errors and i will take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code once**

```
$sub = $this->createQueryBuilder('data');
 $sub->select('d')
     ->from($this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata($entityClass)->getName(), 'd')
     ->where("d.number != ''")
     ->orderBy('d.time', 'DESC');

 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('data');
 $qb->select('p')
    ->from($sub->getDQL(),'p')
    ->groupBy('p.number');
```